# My code will make the program think the user input nothing at all. How can I keep the values?

Tags: html, django, onclick

I have those input fields, and I want them to clear out once the user hits Send.

The code below lets the user input data into multiple fields:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

But, after the user hit Send, the fields won't get refreshed. The user will have to remove all the text manually. How can I clear the fields so that the user can continue inputting and submitting data?

[image]

`views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import ContactForm

def contact(request):
    template = "contact.html"

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: But if you submit the form, not with an AJAX request, then the browser will load the response. So I don't see why you reset the form. You can simply produce a response with a new (clean) form.

Comment: I want to be able to clear the fields each time a user clicks Send, so more users can input data and submit.

Comment: but if there are multiple users, they each get an individual form. The page is not some "shared memory object" that spans over all users.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: can you share the view? I think you simply do not construct a new form in the view.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of a succesful POST request, you can create a new form:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ContactForm

def contact(request):
    template = "contact.html"

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

However in the case of a *succesful* POST request, it is common to make a *redirect*, this is the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ContactForm

def contact(request):
    template = "contact.html"
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(contact)
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```